# Print out parameters at every 100 iterations

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I am fitting some data to my model. I would like to print out parameters values say every 100 iterations (or 500) to check values getting steady state. Actually, I have a larger data and more complicate model than this and I am planning to set `MaxIteration->10^5` and print out values at every 10^4 step. I don't wanna plot result at every step. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
data1= {{1.*10^-10, 380.38}, {0.001, 457.448}, {0.00215443, 548.79}, {0.00464159, 7651.56}, {0.01, 13596.2}, {0.0215443,  16416.9}, {0.0464159, 16922.2}, {0.1, 18109.2}, {0.215443, 19106.4}, {0.464159, 19317.9}, {1., 19797.5}, {10., 20514.7}};

f1[i_] := (c1 i^p1)/(is1^p1 + i^p1) + \[Epsilon]1

parameters1 = {\[Epsilon]1, c1, p1, is1};

model1 = Sum[ (Log10[f1@data1[[i, 1]]] - Log10[data1[[i, 2]]])^2, {i,12}];

fit1 = NMinimize[{model1, c1 > 0 && \[Epsilon]1 > 0 && 0 < p1 < 10 && 10^-10 < is1 <= 10}, parameters1, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", MaxIterations ->2000]

Thread[{\[Epsilon]1, c1, p1, is1} = parameters1 /. Last@fit1];

Show[LogLogPlot[f1[i], {i, 10^-4, 10.02}, PlotRange -> All,   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400],  ListLogLogPlot[Rest@data1, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`StepMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) or [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) together with `Reap` / `Sow` to extract intermediate results from fitting functions. See [Collecting expressions during evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html).

Below I am using your definitions of `parameters1`, `model1`, and `f1`, but 
I changed the definition of fit1, and added `intermediates` to collect the running values of the parameters. I also did not assign the values to the parameters, which would give you trouble when running the code more than once; instead I use a replacement rule to plot the fit (see argument of `LogLogPlot`).

```
{fit1, intermediates} = Reap[
   NMinimize[
    {model1, 
     c1 > 0 && ϵ1 > 0 && 0 < p1 < 10 && 10^-10 < is1 <= 10}, 
    parameters1,
    MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution",
    StepMonitor :> Sow[parameters1]
    ]
   ];

Show[
 LogLogPlot[f1[i] /. Last@fit1, {i, 10^-4, 10.02}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400],
 ListLogLogPlot[Rest@data1, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: fit]

(Note that at least in this case the differential evolution method was much slower than the default chosen by `NMinimize`. You may want to experiment with your actual data.)

Now you can plot the evolution of the parameter values during the fit. You can post-select how many to plot as well; for instance, below I will plot one value for each 2nd iteration:

```
ListPlot /@ Transpose@intermediates[[1, ;; ;; 2]]
```

[image: params]

Comment: Wow!! This is awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Quick question: How can I make sure I am finding global minimum?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci It can be very, very hard to know whether you found a global minimum, or you just got stuck in a local one. You might be interested in this tutorial: [Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html).

Comment: Thank you for reference and kind help.